# Solve every possible combination of #s in a list that add up to a predetermined # w/out repeating # in list more than how many times they appear?

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm trying to figure out how to loop through a list and solve every possible combination of numbers that add up to a predetermined value without repeating any numbers in the combination more than how ever many times they appear on the list.

Here's the code I tried:

```
import itertools

magicnumber = float(input("Enter desired quantity : "))

lst = [2.7, 9.9, 5.4, 9.0, 5.4, 8.1, 6.3, 4.5, 5.4]

for L in range(0, len(lst)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(lst, L):
        b = sum(float(i) for i in subset)
            
        if b == magicnumber:
            print(subset)
```

I tried solving all combinations that add up to **18.9** in the list, but can't figure out how to not have the numbers repeat when adding more than they appear on the list.

I want it to return all combinations like below that add up to **18.9** using only the numbers in the list once, and more than once only how ever many times they repeat.

The result I want to get is:

```
(9.9, 9.0)
(5.4, 5.4, 8.1)
(2.7, 6.3, 4.5, 5.4)
```

What I'm currently getting:

```
(9.9, 9.0)
(5.4, 9.0, 4.5)
(5.4, 5.4, 8.1)
(5.4, 8.1, 5.4)
(9.0, 5.4, 4.5)
(9.0, 4.5, 5.4)
(5.4, 8.1, 5.4)
(8.1, 6.3, 4.5)
(2.7, 6.3, 4.5, 5.4)
```

Comment: Sorting might be of use here.

Comment: Why doesn't your desired result include (5.4, 9.0, 4.5)?

Comment: You CAN'T use equality here.  With two exceptions, none of the numbers in your list (including 18.9) can be expressed in binary.  They will all be approximations, and round-off errors means they would add up.  You need to use a "close to" function that checks, for example, that `abs(a-b) < 0.0001` or something similar.

Comment: @ScottHunter I need the results to use the numbers only as many times as they appear in the list. If we used (5.4, 9.0, 4.5), it wouldn't give me a result where all the numbers are used at least once, but not more than the number of times they appear on the list.

Comment: So, once you use a number in a subset, you can't use it again?  Is the goal to use as many of the numbers as possible?  That's a much more difficult problem, because it requires backtracking.  You will have to remove each set from the master set and continue processing.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, the numbers should all be used at least once. Thank you. Looking into backtracking now.

Comment: Once you deal with the floating-point issue (scaling up everything by 10 would work in this particular case), this is easily solved by recursion.  The number of combinations from a list that sum to a given total (let's call that `NC(L, T)` is the sum of the number of combinations from the rest of the list, ignoring the first one (that's just `NC(L[1:], T)`) plus the number of combinations from the rest of the list, including the first one (which is `NC(L[1:], T-L[0])`).

Comment: You don't mean "at least once".  You mean "at most once".  There are many data sets where you will not be able to consume all of the input.

Comment: 1,2,3,7 magic 10. Do you want to return 1,2,7 or 3,7? What about 1,2,3,7,8 magic 10? 1,2,7 or 3,7+2,8?

Answer (score 0):

I would get all possible combination as you have stated in your question and then just check if the combination is valid:

```py
import itertools
from collections import Counter


def is_combination_valid(subset, cnt):
    cnt_subset = Counter(subset)

    if any(cnt[c] < cnt_subset.get(c, float("inf")) for c in subset):
        return False

    for v in subset:
        cnt[v] -= 1

    return True


magicnumber = 18.9
lst = [2.7, 9.9, 5.4, 9.0, 5.4, 8.1, 6.3, 4.5, 5.4]

cnt = Counter(lst)

for L in range(0, len(lst) + 1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(lst, L):
        b = sum(subset)
        if b == magicnumber and is_combination_valid(subset, cnt):
            print(subset)
```

Prints:

```
(9.9, 9.0)
(5.4, 5.4, 8.1)
(2.7, 6.3, 4.5, 5.4)
```

---

With:

```py
magicnumber = 18.9
lst = [8.1, 9.9, 5.4, 9.0, 5.4, 8.1, 6.3, 4.5, 5.4]
```

It prints:

```py
(9.9, 9.0)
(8.1, 5.4, 5.4)
(8.1, 6.3, 4.5)
```

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes, you're right! I must check if the count is enough, not just equal zero.

Comment: Now you can use Counter operations to check whether it's a submultiset and to subtract it.

Comment: Hmm, I see submultiset check was only added in Python 3.10. But that was almost two years ago already, so I'd still use it :-)